# How to make column data clickable with link in yajra datatable laravel 5.7

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables, laravel-5.7, yajra-datatable

Im trying make the row values of the ID clickable that links to another view. This is achievable using the regular datatable from jQuery in the front-end like: `<td><h6><a href="/users/{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->id }}</a></h6></td>`. But how do I do it using yajra? For some reason, yajrabox.com won't load in my end so I couldn't read their docs. I can't find relevant tutorials either. Here's what I have so far.

UsersController:

```
public function index()
{        
    return view('users.index');
}

public function yajraDT()
{
    return Datatables::of(User::query())->make(true);
}
```

index.blade.php:

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Laravel DataTables Tutorial Example</h2>
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tableDT">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-left">Id</th>
                <th class="text-left">First Name</th>
                <th class="text-left">Last Name</th>
                <th class="text-left">Email</th>
                <th class="text-left">Gender</th>
                @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->type == "Admin")
                <th class="text-left">Actions</th>
                @endif
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

```
<script>
     $(function() {
           $('#tableDT').DataTable({
           processing: true,
           serverSide: true,
           ajax: '{{ url('users/yajraDT') }}',
           columns: [
                    { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
                    { data: 'first_name', name: 'first_name' },
                    { data: 'last_name', name: 'last_name' },
                    { data: 'email', name: 'email' },
                    { data: 'gender', name: 'gender' }
                 ]
        });
     });
</script>
```

routes.web:

```
Route::get('users/yajraDT', 'UsersController@yajraDT');
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

Comment: So you want to return RAW column data to blade like <a></a> or <button></button> ? is that correct ?

Comment: @ViperTecPro yes that's correct I want to return an HTML link in the column data for it to become clickable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass a render function to your data like so:

```
{ data: 'id', name: 'id', render:function(data, type, row){
    return "<a href='/users/"+ row.id +"'>" + row.id + "</a>"
}},
```

This will wrap all of the `<td>` in that anchor tag. I am wondering if you will run into problems with DataTable's own ID attribute, though. So I'm not sure if the row.id will return *your* id or DataTables. If you add a `console.log(row)` before the return statement you should find the object that you can manipulate in the render function, so you should be able to find what you need in there if `row.id` isn't returning the correct id.

Comment: Thank you just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 5):

You can use rawColumns api from controller. Check this: http://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/raw-columns

```
$users = User::query();
return Datatables::of($users)
    ->addColumn('id', function ($user) {
        return '<h6><a href="/users/'. $user->id .'">'. $user->id .'</a></h6>';
    })
    ->rawColumns(['id'])
    ->make(true);
```